# Gluing morphisms to projective space (Hartshrone thm II.7.1)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm confused about gluing morphisms to the projective space, which seems pretty obvious but I can't understand the subtle point. Let me write the setting from Hartshrone II.7.1: $X$ is a scheme over a ring $A$, and $\mathscr{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on X, which is generated by global sections $s_0,\dots,s_n$. We want to construct the unique $A$-morphism $\varphi:X \to \mathbb{P}^n_A$ such that $\mathscr{L}\simeq \varphi^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$ and $s_i$ is an image of $x_i$ by pullback. Let $X_i = \{p\in X|(s_i)_p \notin m_p\mathcal{L}_p\}$. We obtain this by gluing morphisms $X_i\to U_i$, given by the ring map $A[y_0,\dots,y_n] \to \Gamma(X_i, \mathcal{O}_X)$ sending $y_j=x_j/x_i \mapsto s_j/s_i$.

Now in $X_i\cap X_j$, restricted morphism $X_i\cap X_j\to U_i\cap U_j$ is given by the ring map $A[x_0,\dots,x_n]_{(x_ix_j)}\to \Gamma(X_i\cap X_j, \mathcal{O}_X)$, and we get identical map from localizing $X_i\to U_i$ and $X_j \to U_j$. My question is, since $U_i\simeq \text{Spec } A[y_0,\dots,y_n]$ is an isomorphism, isn't two maps from restricting $X_i\to U_i, X_j\to U_j$ are same up to automorphism of $A[x_0,\dots,x_n]_{(x_ix_j)}$?

Comment: Yes, they are same because $U_i$ is isomorphic to $U_j$ over $U_{ij}$.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrased well. To glue $X_i\to U_i$ and $X_j\to U_j$, their restrictions $\varphi_1, \varphi_2: X_i\cap X_j\to U_i\cap U_j$ should be same. But rings for $U_i$ or $U_i\cap U_j$ are given by isomorphism, so I'm not sure how can we say two maps are same? It is clear that $\varphi_1=f\circ\varphi_2$ for some automorphism $f$ of $U_i\cap U_j$, but why $f$ is indeed an identity?